# How to update return key after programmatically removing text in UITextField

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield

When using `enablesReturnKeyAutomatically` in a `UITextField`, it is supposed to disable the return key when the text field contains no text or an empty string. If you programmatically clear the text, for example upon tapping a button, this will disable the return key. However if you clear it in the `textFieldShouldReturn:` function, the button remains enabled.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.text = nil
    return true
}
```

How can one inform the text field the text content has changed when it's cleared upon pressing return, triggering the return key to become disabled as is appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

```
textField?.text = nil
textField?.sendActionsForControlEvents(.ValueChanged)
```

This will work.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this still results in the return key remaining enabled.

Comment: I updated my answer. i guess you are using third party keyboard, in third party keybord, it won't work.

Comment: I'm not using a third party keyboard. But it does work if you clear it using a button as you've shown, but if you clear it in `textFieldShouldReturn` the button remains enabled. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Make check mark in auto enable return key. After that give empty string or make programatically text in textfield nil , it works fine.